# Send Email with multiple attachements using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to send attachment using following code. But i keep getting error `Could not find a part of the path`.

I am Calling sendEmail function from `ApplyForJob.aspx.cs` file which is in under folder `App_Code/Helper.cs`

Below is the part of `SendEmail` function

```
        // Create a new Smpt Client 
        var mailclient = new SmtpClient();

        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment1;
        attachment1 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/" + am1));
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1);
```

I have changed path to `~/App_Data/uploads/" + am1` 
 `App_Data/uploads/" + am1` 
`../App_Data/uploads/" + am1`

But none of the options seem to be working.

How can i make path correctly point towards file which is stored in `App_Data/Uploads/`

General Folder Structure

```
App_Data
..Upload
....resume1.docx
....resume2.docx
....resume3.docx
....resume4.docx
....resume4.docx
App_Code
..Helper.cs
English
..Default.aspx
..Default.aspx.cs
..ApplyForJob.aspx
..ApplyForJob.aspx.cs
Spanish
```

Comment: +am1?? what is that??

Comment: am1 is filename variable

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath
```

Other Details: http://forums.asp.net/t/1813648.aspx
http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
  Server.MapPath("Path as String")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will locate the Example.xml file in the App_Data folder
 (App_Data is a good place to put data files.)

```
attachment1 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Example.xml"));
```

This will locate the Example.txt file in the root directory.
This can be used in a file in any directory in the application.

```
attachment1 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Example.txt"));
```